# how to develop a multi player chess?

Tags: c#, .net, chess

I wana develop a multi-player chess using c# but I don't have any idea of how to implement the restriction rules of chess with c# to be honest i've never done even a little bit of game programming in my life so that I don't have any idea of how to work in this area.

is there any  simple sample of chess program source code out there?
frankly i wasn't successful with searching about chess source code or how to implement the moves rules in chess.

so if you think that you can help me that would be appreciated.

regards.

Comment: Perhaps you should start with something simpler?

Comment: austin powers? Is it a troll question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was the first result from the Bing.com search "programming chess":

https://www.chessprogramming.org/Main_Page

It seems to cover all the bases, for player vs. player or player vs. computer.

Comment: This is definitely the most comprehensive resource out there. You got you answer in a split second before I did. :)

Comment: @LBushkin: It looks pretty nice. :) I've been digging through it, there is a lot of great info there. I wish there was a site like this for programming Go, as I generally prefer that over Chess myself (however both are excellent strategy games.)

Comment: Wow people actually use Bing ?

Comment: I LOVE Bing! It returns great results on the first page, and I've gotten several hundred bucks back by using their shopping search. :)

Answer (score 0):

Chess is a complex game.  If you are new to programming, or this type of programming, I might suggest that you start with something similar but simpler (checkers comes to mind).  This way you can get something working quickly and learn the basics (such as representing a board, moving pieces, etc) without suffering through the headaches associated with all of the particulars of chess.

Comment: @danben: actually writing a **BASIC** chess engine isn't that hard. The hard part comes tweaking the engine to improve playability and balance.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a chess board as a 2 dimensional array with rows and columns, it consists of 64 squares so you have 8 * 8.  So that is the base of your program.  The next thing you have to think about is pieces, and rules behind the pieces.  In addition, what are the legal moves for a knight, a pawn, a queen, etc.

It isn't complex if you break it all up into smaller tid bits, but I have never coded such an animal :).  The rules can actually be stored in some sort of resource file or database.  And you simply check if the move being made on the array is a valid move.  If it is allow it, otherwise don't.

That is just a small start...

Answer (score 0):

I would start [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=open+source+chess+engine+.net).

The first thing would be the creation of a chess engine. From there the rest of the code should practically write itself.